# I can't end an autostarted X11 application over SSH

Tags: ssh, x11, expect

I would like to have an SSH connection be closed as soon as the user quits a program that is started with the SSH connection. My current script is

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set login "pi"
set addr "192.168.0.102"
set pw "password"

spawn ssh -X $login@$addr
expect "$login@$addr\'s password:"
send "$pw\r"
expect "#"
send "wpa_gui; exit\n"
interact
```

When I quit the wpa_gui application, I get

```
logout
```

No prompt or anything after that, it just says `logout`. I have to close the window with `^C`

If I try to do something similar without X11, it works

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set login "pi"
set addr "192.168.0.102"
set pw "password"

spawn ssh $login@$addr
expect "$login@$addr\'s password:"
send "$pw\r"
expect "#"
send "man ls; exit\n"
interact
```

That will close the shell window as soon as I `q`uit the `man` page.

If I start the wpa gui manually:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set login "pi"
set addr "192.168.0.102"
set pw "password"

spawn ssh -X $login@$addr
expect "$login@$addr\'s password:"
send "$pw\r"
expect "#"
interact
```

and then in the command line:

```
$ wpa_gui
$ exit
logout
```

the same thing happens. So the problem must be in the X11 area, rather than running commands on SSH startup.

Please help

-Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

I know ssh won't fully close a connection if there is still an X session running through its tunnel. So it may be that `wpa_gui` does't really stop when you think it does. It sounds like it is a WiFi tool, which may add an icon to your system tray...

Comment: It does go into the system tray. But I right click on that and quit it . The terminal then executes `exit` but that does not close the terminal window.

Comment: Ok, I'm at a loss here. But can't you let `expect` forcefully close the session when it sees the 'logout' at the end? Like you pressed ^C?

Comment: I think it is possible. I am no great `expect` expert. But I will google it.